# How to decrease point light effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have two renders in Cycles and EEVEE, I want to achieve in Cycles the same effect like I have in EEVEE. I don't want to light the entire room. I tried using nodes it doesn't work.

[image: cycles render]

[image: eevee render]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Light Falloff node to adjust how light falls-off with distance. See associated answer [Custom light falloff in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101488/29586). Switching to Linear falloff may get the effect you're looking for.

Alternatively, (also as described in the linked answer) you can use the Ray Length to manipulate the lamp emission strength directly - in order to get finer control of light strength over distance.

Comment: I saw a lot o tha node setup but cant do that effect :(

Answer (score 1):

I went into Color Management and was able to get something close.

[image]

This is an effect that is probably easier to achieve in the compositor, but I think one thing that's happening here is you've used a custom distance on the light in Eevee, and that option does not directly correspond to any setting in cycles.

Edited for correction: see Rich's answer for light node usage.

Comment: maybe compositor will be esier, but what about i want this effect on only one light source in the scene